# Recommended secure approach to confirming an URL is called by a legitimate caller

Tags: security

I'm using a CRON on AppEngine and the cron calls my web app at a specific app.

I only want to execute functionality when called by my AppEngine app.

What's is/are recommended approach to confirming that the caller is legitimate? I don't wish to rely on no one else knowing the specific URL.

Comment: is that IP of the CRON machine static?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini AppEngine doesn't expose Machine details. CodeCas ter has come back with an AppEngine-specific approach/solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid having to authenticate the request from cron at all.

- Create a [backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/); let it be named `cronbackend`. Mark it as *private*.
- Move your handler that cron needs to touch to that backend.
- Now the URL has changed: instead of `myapp.appspot.com/url` it has become `cronbackend-dot-myapp.appspot.com/url`. Let cron use this URL.

Since your backend is private, it is not exposed to the outside world at all; only your frontend (your application), your cron, or manager of your queues can access it. Also, handlers on a backend can run for significantly longer.

Note that a backend and a frontend look like separate apps, are deployed independently, and billed separately. This allows for added flexibility, though.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [RESTful web service - how to authenticate requests from other services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134082/restful-web-service-how-to-authenticate-requests-from-other-services) on StackOverflow, you have to use a shared secret of some sort.

That can be a token, username and password or a client certificate for example.